# What could be reasons for high MAE and MSE in Keras?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras

My MAE and MSE quite high. But the training data (not including test data 20%) (1030, 23) instances (after applied IQR and Z-score). By the way, all the categorical columns had been fully encoded.

```
Epoch: 1900, loss:50195632.3010,  mae:3622.3535,  mse:50195636.0000,  val_loss:65308249.2427,  val_mae:4636.2290,  val_mse:65308244.0000,
```

Below is my setting for Keras.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(dftrain.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

EPOCHS = 2000

history = model.fit(
    normed_train_data, 
    train_labels,
    epochs=EPOCHS, 
    validation_split = 0.2, 
    verbose=0,
    callbacks=[tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])
```

What do you think?

Comment: High `MAE` even after 2000 `epochs` means that the model is too small. Try increasing the number of `Dense` Layers. Also print and check if the inputs and outputs are passed on to the model correctly ( maybe some bug during `normalization`).

Comment: You mean increasing the number of each Dense Layersor add other Dense Layers.

Comment: These absolute loss values mean nothing. How does it compare to a baseline (e.g. a linear regression or naively predicting a subsample mean/median)?

Comment: Both will help. What is your task? Classification or Regression? What type of data?

Comment: It's regression. Real estate data.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. MAE works only for regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"High" `MAE` itself is relative and varies according to the data and there could be multiple factors contributing towards it.

If you are getting started, I d recommend you to perform Exploratory Data 
Analysis (EDA) and come up with features and also prepare that data for training.
Once you verify the data, try tuning the parameters of the model to suit your usecase. ML is more about experimenting than about coding.

Notebooks like these in Kaggle will help you get started.

1. [Neural Network Model for House Prices](https://www.kaggle.com/diegosiebra/neural-network-model-for-house-prices-keras)
2. [Comprehensive data exploration with Python](https://www.kaggle.com/pmarcelino/comprehensive-data-exploration-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons actually. My quick guesses would be your dataset. The data for training. Is it compatible to the model's expectations? (shapes, formats etc.) Like, in case of text classification, are the texts encoded before feeding to the model.
Are the labels correctly, transformed to neural network expectations?

If yes, rest will be on your network definition, are you using the right loss function, layers etc?

Try a basic model architecture for your problem, this basic architecture model can be taken from implementations for the similar problem found on internet. This will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already mentioned some good points, but another thing you can do is to normalize your data if you haven't already. [NNs are highly sensitive to this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn/352037#352037). Some methods you can try here are [Batch Normalization](https://towardsdatascience.com/backpropagation-and-batch-normalization-in-feedforward-neural-networks-explained-901fd6e5393e), [Standard Scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) or [Min-Max Scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).

Also, if your model is overfitting (training loss decreasing, but not validation loss), consider adding regularization in the form of [Dropout](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-regularization-deep-learning-models-keras/) between your layers and see if it improves.

These links might be helpful:

1. [link1](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607)
2. [link2](http://theorangeduck.com/page/neural-network-not-working)